# Need help with symbolic tensor calculus using Kronecker products

Tags: simplifying-expressions, tensors

I am quite new with Mathematica. I need to do symbolic tensor calculations but what I try does not seem to work. I have found similar questions to mine, but I need a generalization

Specifically, if `X`, `Y` are (2 x 2) matrices and `a, b, c, d` are numbers, I want to calculate the Kronecker product of

```
(Cos[a] X1 + Sin[a] Y1) ⊗ (Cos[b] X2 - Sin[b] Y2) .
   (Cos[c] X3 + Sin[c] Y3) ⊗ (Cos[d] X2 - Sin[d] Y2)
```

such that

```
(A ⊗ B).(C ⊗ D) = (A.C) ⊗ (B.D)
```

Additionally, within these calculations, I want to teach Mathematica some commutation relations between `X` and `Y` that it should be used for simplification, etc.

Furthermore, how do I express identity as a symbol?, which I've asked here: [Implementing the symbolic identity matrix $I$](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/235897/implementing-the-symbolic-identity-matrix-i)

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: `CircleTimes[x_, y_] := KroneckerProduct[x, y];
(a\[CircleTimes]b).(c\[CircleTimes]d) == (a.c)\[CircleTimes](b.d) // 
  TensorExpand;
((Cos[a] X1 + Sin[a] Y1)\[CircleTimes](Cos[b] X2 - 
      Sin[b] Y2)).((Cos[c] X3 + Sin[c] Y3)\[CircleTimes](Cos[d] X2 - 
      Sin[d] Y2)) // TensorExpand` ？

Comment: @cvgmt, thank you! Is there a way to make Mathematica display Kronecker products with the mathematical symbol instead of writting it out as well?

Comment: @cvgmt, is there a way to generalize that? So instead of ```A\[CircleTimes]B``` to ```A\[CircleTimes]B\[CircleTimes]C...``` ?