# Implementing the symbolic identity matrix $I$

Tags: symbolic, tensors

I am working with symbolic tensors within Mathematica and I wanted to ask if there is a way to have a symbolic identity tensor.

Comment: See `TagSet`? E.g. `id /: (id[n_].m_ /; Dimensions[m][[1]] == n) = m`? You'll likely need a decent number of rules though, and the order they are input does matter.

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28563/symbolic-tensor-simplifications-and-the-identity-matrix

Comment: @MichaelE2  how to create a fourth order identity tensor in MMA?