# Can I speed up my tensor calculations?

Tags: performance-tuning, tensors

I am running this code now for hours, which is not even that hard actually, but Mathematica seems to have troubles with it:

```
CircleTimes[x_, y_] := KroneckerProduct[x, y]; 
(a⊗b).(c⊗d) == (a.c)⊗(b.d) // TensorExpand;

X1 = Cos[Subscript[a, 1]]*X + Sin[Subscript[a, 1]]*Z
Z1 = Cos[Subscript[b, 1]]*X - Sin[Subscript[b, 1]]*Z
X2 = Cos[Subscript[a, 2]]*X + Sin[Subscript[a, 2]]*Z
Z2 = Cos[Subscript[b, 2]]*X - Sin[Subscript[b, 1]]*Z
X3 = Cos[Subscript[a, 3]]*X + Sin[Subscript[a, 3]]*Z
Z3 = Cos[Subscript[b, 3]]*X - Sin[Subscript[b, 3]]*Z

X1Z2 = CircleTimes[X1, Z2]
S1 = Simplify[TensorExpand[CircleTimes[X1Z2, Z3]]]
Z1X2 = CircleTimes[Z1, X2]
S2 = CircleTimes[Z1X2, Z3]
Z1Z2 = CircleTimes[Z1, Z2]
S3 = CircleTimes[Z1Z2, X3]

Pr= TensorExpand[S1.S2.S3]
```

which is nothing but expanding simple calculations, but Mathematica really has trouble with it. I know that the result will be lengthy, but it's not hard or very sophisticated.

Is there a way to make Mathematica run faster? I need all those symbols though.

Another thing, I would like to implement a symbolic identity tensor $I$, How do I teach Mathematica that?, which I asked here: [Implementing the symbolic identity matrix $I$](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/235897/implementing-the-symbolic-identity-matrix-i)

Comment: You have not provided the definition of `CircleTimes` so nobody can help you yet. If `CircleTimes` is a synonym for `KroneckerProduct` then I'm not surprised it takes a long time as the dimensions and expression leaf count blow up. What is the purpose of your code and what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I did provide the definition above I think as you can see in the first row. It is a Kronecker product that respects the multiplication of tensors as defined above.

Comment: Thanks it's now possible to reproduce the issue. Are you expecting Mathematica to give a known answer for the `TensorExpand`? If it's taking too long the result probably too large to represent. Also what is the purpose of the code?

Comment: You probably shouldn't keep adding the same extra question to every post. Q&As should focus on one principal issue, and you have already asked about an identity tensor.