# Identity operator of unspecified dimensions

Tags: symbolic

I would like to create a function which can can take a symbolic square matrix $m$ and returns
$m \otimes I$. Where $I$ is the idenity operator of same dimensions as $m$. The actual function I am interested in is more complicated but this is the minimal functionality that I am interested in.

An implementation that would work for non-symbolic (I just mean concrete) matrices `m` could for example be the following

```
mKronI[m_] := KroneckerProduct[m, IdentityMatrix[Length[m]]]
```

Then, inserting some specific matrix, say
$$ m = \left( \begin{matrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{matrix} \right) $$
should return
$$ \left( \begin{matrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{matrix} \right) \otimes \left( \begin{matrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{matrix} \right)  = \left( \begin{matrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{matrix} \right)$$
Indeed:

```
In[]:m = {{1, 0}, {0, 0}};
In[]:mKronI[m]
```

```
Out[]:{{1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}}
```

However, such a function returns an error when a symbolic variable is passed as it is unable to determine the `Length` of this variable.

Would it be possible to let the function simply return 'its definition' in such a case? Such that we would have

```
In[]:answ = mKronI[m]
```

```
Out[]:KroneckerProduct[m, IdentityMatrix[Length[m]]]
```

which then would also ensure that whenever `m` will be specified later, `answ` will automatically be evaluated to the correct value.

In simple terms I would like similar behavior for the function as we have for the following trivial example which mixes symbolic variables and variables for which the value is specified

```
In[]:c = a + b
Out[]:a + b
```

Then, if we specify `b`

```
In[]:b = 1
```

And check the value for `c`, we get

```
In[]:c
```

```
Out[]:1+a
```

I hope my question is clear. I have looked into a number of posts [Implementing the symbolic identity matrix](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/235897/implementing-the-symbolic-identity-matrix-i) and [Symbolic tensor simplifications and the identity matrix](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28563/symbolic-tensor-simplifications-and-the-identity-matrix) but I don't understand the answers given there well and also I doubt if they would help me. I also fiddled around with some things as `Assuming[m \[Element] Matrices[{n, n}], KroneckerProduct[m, IdentityMatrix[n]]]`) but so far without luck.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Make a conditional definition like: `mKronI[m_] /; MatrixQ[m] := 
 KroneckerProduct[m, IdentityMatrix[Length[m]]]`

Comment: Why not just use `SetDelayed` for `answ`? Or not invoke `mKronI` until you have an actual matrix set for your variable you use in `mKronI`? Are you aware that you don’t have to use only `m` in your `mKronI`? You could set something like `matrixThatIsNotm` to a matrix and invoke `mKronI[matrixThatIsNotm]`. I apologize if this is a misunderstanding of your problem, but it seems to me that you could simply change slightly your method of programming to not generate this problem?

Comment: Most importantly I want Mathematica to not give an error when using the function with a symbolic input so that the result can be used in further calculations. Your solution @DanielHuber does that so thank you! I didn't know about ```Condition```. @CA Trevillian, if I use ```SetDelayed``` for ```answ``` it will not directly yield an error, but it will the first time I use it somewhere. But I don't understand your suggestion. What do you mean by setting something to a matrix? Similar to Element[m, Matrices[{n, n}]]? But you may be right about my rogramming methods,maybe I should reconsider them.